# Adding libraries to visual studio as a whole folder c++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

How would I go about adding a whole folder to the external dependencies?
I can link folders to it no problem but it seems to grab all the files from the folder, not just link the folder.

I'm using the latest visual studio.

I need to be able to do ' #include "openssl/ssl.h" ' but I'm only able to link it so that '#include "ssl.h" ' would work. Help?

Comment: ***How would I go about adding a whole folder to the external dependencies?*** You add the path to the folder containing the `openssl` folder to your `Additional Include Directories` At least that is how I have done this for the last 20+ years in Visual Studio.

Comment: I rightclick under the solution, go into properties, configuration properties and under VC++ Directories & C/C++ & Linker, I add to additional libraries and additional include directories the location of the folder that holds the folder that holds the .h files like you say (D:\OpenSSL-Win64\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)). It doesn't seem to work when I include the folder name but works perfectly fine with just the header names.

Comment: Does `D:\OpenSSL-Win64\include` contain a `openssl` folder?

Comment: yes, the only thing it contains is an openssl folder

Comment: It should work if inside of that `openssl` folder there is a `ssl.h` file and you added `D:\OpenSSL-Win64\include` to your `Additional Include Directories`. Remember though this setting will apply to only the selected configuration(s) so if you apply it to debug you still have to set it for release...

Answer (score 0):

Aha! When setting 'Additional Include Directories' it turns out in the configurations I had to select 'All Configurations' and 'All Platforms' for the Include Directory to work correctly, as I had set the wrong ones.